Complexity of rectangular matrix multiplication
It is well-known that there are numerous optimization techniques and decreasing complexities for square matrix multiplication. However, are there any optimization methods for rectangular matrix multiplication of dimensions $n×m$ and $m×p$? Despite extensive search online, I couldn't find any relevant literature. Wikipedia only outlines the textbook complexity of $O(nmp)$ for this operation.
If $n \gg m$ and $p \gg m$, could we potentially decompose the matrices into $\lceil n/m \rceil × \lceil p/m \rceil$ square matrices for computation? Are there any other more general computational methods available?
Thank you for any insights or references you can provide.
